# Telerik RibbonBar Localization

Tags: c#, localization, multilingual, telerik-radribbonbar

Our application supports multi-language but there is a problem with radribbon.

We use this code to change language and it works except the ribbon

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(langCode);
        SuspendLayout();
        ComponentResourceManager manager = new ComponentResourceManager(this.GetType());
        manager.ApplyResources(this, "$this");
        ApplyResources(manager, this.Controls);
        ResumeLayout();



private void ApplyResources(ComponentResourceManager manager,Control.ControlCollection ctls)
        {

            //all controls
            foreach (Control ctl in ctls)
            {
                manager.ApplyResources(ctl, ctl.Name);
                Trace.WriteLine("Control: " + ctl.GetType().ToString());
                ApplyResources(manager, ctl.Controls);
            }
        }
```

the problem is the ribbonbar does not have children. The tabs are in the CommandTabs collection and the items are not derived by the windows.controls.

so what should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, its a bit dirty way but it works for me

```
  private void ApplyResources(ComponentResourceManager manager, object controls)
    {
        if (controls is Control.ControlCollection)
        {
            var ctls = (Control.ControlCollection)controls;
            //all controls
            foreach (Control ctl in ctls)
            {

                if (ctl is RadRibbonBar)
                {
                    var tabs = ((RadRibbonBar)ctl).CommandTabs;
                    foreach (RibbonTab tab in tabs)
                    {
                        manager.ApplyResources(tab, tab.Name);
                        ApplyResources(manager, tab.Items);
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    manager.ApplyResources(ctl, ctl.Name);
                    ApplyResources(manager, ctl.Controls);
                }
            }
        }
        else // if (controls is RadItemOwnerCollection)
        {
            var elementCollection = controls as RadItemOwnerCollection;


            foreach (var elem in elementCollection)
            {
                if (elem is RadRibbonBarGroup)
                {
                    var barGroup = elem as RadRibbonBarGroup;
                    manager.ApplyResources(barGroup, barGroup.Name);
                    ApplyResources(manager, barGroup.Items);
                }
                else if (elem is RadRibbonBarButtonGroup)
                {
                    var btnGroup = elem as RadRibbonBarButtonGroup;
                    manager.ApplyResources(btnGroup, btnGroup.Name);
                    ApplyResources(manager, btnGroup.Items);
                }
                else
                {
                    manager.ApplyResources(elem, elem.Name);

                }
            }
        }


    }
```